# How do I run the sed command with input and output as the same file?

Tags: sed

I'm trying to do use the sed command in a shell script where I want to remove lines that read `STARTremoveThisComment` and lines that read `removeThisCommentEND`.

I'm able to do it when I copy it to a new file using

```
sed 's/STARTremoveThisComment//' > test
```

But how do I do this by using the same file as input and output?

Comment: sed -e s/some1/some2/g input.file > output.file;mv output.file input.file

Answer (score 101, accepted):

`sed -i` (or the extended version, `--in-place`) will automate the process normally done with less advanced implementations, that of sending output to  temporary file, then renaming that back to the original.

The `-i` is for in-place editing, and you can also provide a backup suffix for keeping a copy of the original:

```
sed -i.bak fileToChange
sed --in-place=.bak fileToChange
```

Both of those will keep the original file in `fileToChange.bak`.

Keep in mind that in-place editing may not be available in all `sed` implementations but it *is* in GNU `sed` which should be available on all variants of Linux, as per your tags.

If you're using a more primitive implementation, you can use something like:

```
cp oldfile oldfile.bak && sed 'whatever' oldfile >newfile && mv newfile oldfile
```

Comment: worked like a charm! :) this is what i used : `sed -i 's/STARTremoveThisComment//' test`

Comment: Note that `--in-place` is a gnuism and will not work in all versions of sed.  If you expect to use your sed script on non-Linux machines, you cannot use it.

Comment: @william, I did think of that but wasn't too fussed since the question had a Linux tag. I'll clarify.

Comment: NOTE for the Mac you MUST add a parameter for the backup file. So sed -i '.bak' will work. If you do not want two copies of the file you can pass a blank parm:  sed -i ''

Comment: Thanks @RyanHeitner.  To be sure, for mac users if you don't wan't the back you say sed -i '' not sed -i'' (i.e. put a space after the -i)

Answer (score 16):

You can use the flag **-i** for in-place editing and the **-e** for specifying normal script expression:

```
sed -i -e 's/pattern_to_search/text_to_replace/' file.txt
```

To delete lines that match a certain pattern you can use the simpler syntax. Notice the **d** flag:

```
sed -i '/pattern_to_search/d' file.txt
```

Comment: on my mac this also creates a copy of the original file like so file.txt-e, why?

Comment: are you leaving a space between -i and -e? because otherwise it will consider the -e as the SUFFIX for backup. Sed's help shows the description for the -i:   
`-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
        edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)`
I just tested this again on my Linux machine and works fine.

Answer (score 4):

You really should not use sed for that.  This question seems to come up ridiculously often, and it seems very strange that it does since the general solution is so trivial.  It seems bizarre that people want to know how to do it in sed, and in python, and in ruby, etc.  If you want to have a filter operate on an input and overwrite it, use the following simple script:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
in=${1?No input file specified}
mv $in ${bak=.$in.bak}
shift
"$@" < $bak > $in
```

Put that in your path in an executable file name `inline`, and then the problem is solved in general.  For example:

```
inline input-file sed -e s/foo/bar/g
```

Now, if you want to add logic to keep multiple backups, or if you have some options to change the backup naming scheme, or whatever, you fix it in one place.  What's the command line option to get 1-up counters on the backup file when processing a file in-place with `perl`?  What about with `ruby`?  Is the option different for `gnu-sed`?  How does `awk` handle it?  The whole friggin' point of unix is that tools do one thing only.  Handling logic for backup files is a second thing, and needs to be factored out.  If you are implementing a tool, do not add logic to create backup files.  Tell your users to use a 2nd tool for that.  Integration is bad.  Modularity is good.  That is the unix way.

Notice that this script has several problems.  The permissions/mode of the input file may be changed, for example.  I'm sure there are innumerable other issues.  However, by putting the backup logic in a wrapper script, you localize all of these issues and don't have to worry that `sed` overwrites the files and changes mode, while `python` keeps the file in place and does not change the inode (I made up those two cases, the point being that not all tools will use the same logic, while the wrapper script will.)

Comment: Thanks, I like the script and adapted it to my taste

   #!/bin/sh -e
   in=${1?No input file specified}
   mv "$in" ${bak=in.bak}
   shift
   "$@" < "$bak" > $in && rm "$bak" || mv "$bak" "$in"

Comment: I disagree, if `sed` has a function to do it, then I see no reason not to do it.  It also seems to fit what he wants.

Comment: @MarkWeiman The problem is that "sed" does not have that function.  One particular implementation of sed supports that function, and as soon as you try to move your script to a machine that uses a different implementation the script breaks.

Comment: So if you only are planning of using the GNU implementation, then use it.  If you are running multiple platforms, then you are more than likely aware of differences.  As far as I know, if you are using Linux of Mac OS X, both have `sed` with the `-i` flag.  I also checked and FreeBSD has that feature also.

Comment: It seems like you're really angry about having to answer this [again]. I would invite you to consider that not everybody is on the same learning journey as you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible to use the same file for input and output. Though one solution is make a shell script which will save it to another file, delete the old input and rename the output to the input file name.

```
sed -e s/try/this/g input.file > output.file;mv output.file input.file
```

Comment: At the very least shouldn't this be 'sed ... & mv ...' so a sed failure won't overwrite your input with a blank file ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `sponge`

> sponge reads standard input and writes it out to the specified file.
>   Unlike a shell redirect, sponge soaks up all its input before writing
>   the output file. This allows constructing pipelines that read from and
>   write to the same file.

```
cat test | sed 's/STARTremoveThisComment//' | sponge test
```