# Search word then search next word then append

Tags: linux, sed

I'm trying to append hostname in configuration file using `sed`, because there are multiple hosts that I need to add, so I want to to automate it. I am stuck with the following situation:

Example InputFile :

```
#######################################################################
#
#Service: System Uptime

#######################################################################

define service{
        use                            generic-service
        host_name                       host1,host2,host3,host4,host5,host6,host7,host8,host9,host10,host11,host12,host13,host14,host15,host16,host17,host18,host19,host20,host21,host22,host23,host24,host25,host26,host27,host28,host29,host30
        service_description            System Uptime
        is_volatile                    0
        check_period                   24x7
        contact_groups                 Test_group
        notification_options           c,w,r,u
        check_command                  check_nt_uptime
        max_check_attempts             3
        normal_check_interval          1
        retry_check_interval           1
        notification_interval          120
        notification_period            24x7
        }
```

What am trying to achieve is appending new hosts to "host_name" line, but there are so many occurrences of "host_name" in the file, so to add it for a specific service I have searched for "Service: System Uptime" then in the 7th line from there I search "host_name" and append new hosts.

I have done what I want using `sed`:

```
sed   '/Service: System Uptime/{N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;/host_name/s|$|,NewHost|}' input file
```

Now the problem is when there are multiple hosts in there then the above `sed` command fails, it breaks the line and appends the host.

Any suggestions on that?

Comment: Maybe you could try making your question more clear. For instance, illustrate the case that you have problems with with example input and desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your problem and I am unable to reproduce it based on the configuration file snippet you have provided.
Having said that, I believe the following command is roughly equivalent to yours and does not depend on a "number of lines"-based seek.

```
sed   '/Service: System Uptime/,/host_name/{/host_name/s|$|,NewHost|}' input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to use `sed`?  This is a job for `awk`:

```
awk '/#Service: System Uptime/ {a=1} 
  a && /host_name/ { a=0; $0 = $0 ", new_host" } 1' input-file
```

Comment: I'm using awk because no equivalent to `sed -i` in awk

Comment: There is but it is available in `gawk v4.1`.

Comment: Why would you want to use `-i`?!?!  That's what redirection is for. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829514/how-do-i-run-the-sed-command-with-input-and-output-as-the-same-file/10834267#10834267

Comment: input file seems too large that's why I'm using `-i` option

Comment: The size of the file is irrelevant.  Using `-i` with sed is exactly equivalent to doing a redirect and renaming the output file.