# About sed command

Tags: sed

I'm struggling with a `sed` command.

I want to change the IP address in a file to 10.2.22.222:8000

The file contains this.

```
Uri = 10.1.11.111:8000
```

I believe that the following code is good.

```
sed -e "s/[0-9]{1-3}.[0-9]{1-3}.[0-9]{1-3}.[0-9]{1-3}:[0-9]{1-4}/10.2.22.222:8000/"
```

However, it does not work correctly, even though I believe my regular expression to be correct.

What should I do?

Comment: Your regex is incorrect, the range quantifier syntax is `{min,max}`. `sed -E "s/[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}:[0-9]{1,4}/10.2.22.222:8000/"`, see [the demo](https://ideone.com/BesRwb)

Comment: And I have to use option of  "-i" .

Comment: If you need to save the results in the same file, yes. It is just not quite the same across sed versions, so in most cases I leave it for the OP to solve. Or via a comment. Anyway, it is a [solved issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829514/how-do-i-run-the-sed-command-with-input-and-output-as-the-same-file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect, the range quantifier syntax is `{min,max}`, not `{min-max}`. Also, the `-e` option does not help here much since your pattern is POSIX ERE compliant (as the `{x,y}` quantifier braces are not escaped).

Use

```
sed -E 's/[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}:[0-9]{1,4}/10.2.22.222:8000/'
```

Or a POSIX BRE:

```
sed 's/[0-9]\{1,3\}\(\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\)\{3\}:[0-9]\{1,4\}/10.2.22.222:8000/'
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/BesRwb).

Comment: Thank you so much. I have to escape.