# How do I get iconv to output to same file?

Tags: iconv

I have a bunch of .csv files that I want to convert.
And I want to convert the actual file, not output to a new one.
Using this line so far. Unfortunately it outputs all converted data into a file named "{}" :(

```
find . -name '*.csv' -exec iconv -f windows-1252 -t utf-8 > {} {} \;
```

ZSH on MacOs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run the sed command with input and output as the same file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829514/how-do-i-run-the-sed-command-with-input-and-output-as-the-same-file)

Comment: The proposed duplicate is for `sed` but this really applies to any command which involves shell redirection. I could probably find a better duplicate; this is a common FAQ.